# jQuery Tree plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview

I am looking for a jQuery plugin which can do following jobs:

1. Presents a tree view of certain list of objects ( probably only list tags could suffice too for the moment)
2. Every node's subtree is expandable & collapsable
3. List items can be dragged & dropped to alter the tree structure
4. I can retrieve & infer tree structure & do some processing on it in back end.

I have looked at some of the plugins which I could find on "Binging". I am not yet satisfied fully though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [**jsTree**](http://www.jstree.com/). Here is the **[demo](http://www.jstree.com/demo)**.

Second option: [treeview](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/)

Comment: Thanks. It is just perfectly what I wanted. :)